# How to pass index in Vue3 v-for Array Refs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In [document](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/array-refs.html), it gives code:

```html
<div v-for="item in list" :ref="setItemRef"></div>
```

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    let itemRefs = []
    const setItemRef = el => {
      if (el) {
        itemRefs.push(el)
      }
    }
    onBeforeUpdate(() => {
      itemRefs = []
    })
    onUpdated(() => {
      console.log(itemRefs)
    })
    return {
      setItemRef
    }
  }
}
```

But I also want to pass the v-for index into handler, just like this:

```html
// fake code
 <div v-for="(item, index) in navItems" :key="index":ref="setNavItemRefs($el, index)">
   <span>{{ item }}</span>
 </div>
```

How can I bind this `index`?

Answer (score 5):

Try out to define an inline handler like :

```
<div v-for="item in list" :ref="(el)=>setItemRef(el,index)"></div>
```

and

```
 const setItemRef = (el,index) => {
      if (el) {
        itemRefs.push(el)
      }
    }
```

Comment: in search for a similar solution and tried this but got a compilation error on the lambda from vite, would you perhaps know if this construct is possible in vue3 combined with vite?

Comment: could you share with me some code in codesanbox?

Comment: seems to have been some temporary issue with vite or volar, no error with the latest version